# get user location immediately page loads (React)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get user location immediately page loads so i can pass it as a prop to the timeline function. But I am having problems with it. The timeline latitude and longitude props on the timeline are null. How do i fix this please. only dirty tricks that have caused the page to load really slowly have worked so far. I am sure there is a better way. Please help!

```
function Home(){

    const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
    const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null)


    useEffect(() => {
        getCoords()
    }, [])


    const getCoords = async () => {
        const pos = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
        });

        setLatitude(pos.coords.latitude)
        setLongitude(pos.coords.setLongitude)
    };



    return(
        <div>
           <NavBar></NavBar>
           <Timeline latitude={latitude} longitude={longitude}></Timeline>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Maybe look at conditionally rendering the Timeline component if latitude and longitude do not equal null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will try to fetch the location when that component mounts, but it will have another render cycle before those are applied to state.  A common pattern is to only render the component dependent on those props when they're available

```
{latitude && longitude && <Timeline latitude={latitude} longtide={longitude} />}
```